EA App games on Steam don't work
I wanted to try ubuntu for a while, since i used arch also linux mint for maybe half a year by now, and wanted a bit of change.
Went to windows for a while to play Need for Speed Unbound and other EA games, since they work there flawlessly of course.
Today I installed ubuntu, linux version games work fine such as War Thunder, etc...
But NFS Unbound just doesn't want to boot if I try with Lutris or not.
